# Getting multiple shortest paths with PgRouting in one query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, routing, pgrouting

I want to run shortest path algorithm on multiple source&target pairs at once and get a result as a table and process it then.

How do I do this? This query does not work:

```
SELECT a.source, a.target, paths.* 
FROM all_to_all a, shortest_path_astar('...', a.source, a.target, false, false) paths;

ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
```

(btw, all_to_all does not literally mean all to all, :) it's just a number of random pairs)

This does not work either:

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_to_all a, (
   SELECT * FROM shortest_path_astar('...', a.source, a.target, false, false) yyy
) AS t2;
```

Comment: ---- could you please expand on this? i have the same problem but cant get these pairs right? (from an attempted edit of the post]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT 
  source, 
  target,
  (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM  -- or whatever you want to do with the routing result
     (SELECT * FROM shortest_path_astar('...',
       source,
       target,
       false,
       false)
     ) AS foo 
  ) AS cost
FROM all_to_all;
```

Comment: can you help me with this problem of 1-many routing in this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421054/how-to-calculate-the-shortest-route-by-road-from-one-origin-point-to-multiple-de

Answer (score 5):

Here's a query that returns all segments for all source-target combinations:

```
SELECT
    source,
    target,
    shortest_path_astar('SELECT gid AS id, length AS cost, * FROM ways', source, target, false, false) AS segment
FROM
    all_to_all
```

Incredible, inconsistent with SQL syntax, but works!

```
source | target | segment
-------+--------+----------------
     1 |      4 | (1, 2, 0.1357)
     1 |      4 | (2, 3, 0.2468)
     1 |      4 | (3, 4, 0.9)
     1 |      4 | (4, -1, 0)
other sources & targets here
```