# Creating many origin-destination routes with pgRouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I'm using a PostGIS / pgRouting database setup with a road network. I'm trying to create an origin-destination table with the complete route information, so not just the sum of the length, like in [this](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/creating-catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-and-qgis/) post.

I'm trying to get something like this as output table:

```
Origin | Destination | vertex_id | cost
1        2             415         14.2
1        2             508         4.3
1        3             919         2.4
1        3             1024        6.8
```

The following code for calculating a single route works fine, but how do I automate this for a lot of origin-destination pairs?

```sql
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
SELECT gid AS id,
start_id::int4 AS source,
end_id::int4 AS target,
length::float8 AS cost
FROM network',
1, -- start_id
2, -- end_id
false, false);
```

I've tried something with subqueries, like this where I'm getting the start_ids from table `nodes`:

```sql
SELECT id,
(SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
SELECT gid AS id,
start_id::int4 AS source,
end_id::int4 AS target,
length::float8 AS cost
FROM network',
id::int4, -- start_id
450969, -- end_id
false, false))
FROM nodes;
```

But this doesn't work because the subquery returns multiple rows (as expected): `ERROR: subquery must return only one column`. Any help?

Comment: I found a solution to my question in this thread:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/how-to-get-multiple-shortest-paths-with-pgrouting-in-one-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, this is the method I used:

- Creating the routes table from origin 'id' to a single destination:

```sql
CREATE TABLE routes AS
SELECT gid, id,
shortest_path('
SELECT gid AS id,
start_id::int4 AS source,
end_id::int4 AS target,
length::float8 As cost,
* FROM network',
id::int4, -- start_id
935560, -- end_id
false, false) AS segment
FROM nodes;
```

I'm using a single destination (end_id) here, because of the time needed for calculation. This query takes a couple of minutes for a few hundred start_ids. The result is a table with the route information in field 'segment', in the format `(vertex_id, edge_id, cost)`.

- Then I split the segment string into the parts and joined this with my links table using the edge_id:

```sql
CREATE TABLE merge_routes_links AS
SELECT * FROM links
JOIN (
SELECT btrim(split_part(segment::varchar, ',', 1), '()') AS vertex_id
btrim(split_part(segment::varchar, ',', 2), '()') AS edge_id
btrim(split_part(segment::varchar, ',', 3), '()') AS cost
FROM routes) AS route
ON route.edge_id::int4 = links.gid::int4;
```

- Finally I calculated the total length of the routes from origin id to destination and joined this to the merge_routes_links table.

```sql
SELECT id,
sum(length::float8) AS length_route
FROM merge_routes_links
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row for each shortest path query you could for example use `ST_Union(the_geom)`, similar to `sum(cost)` as you mentioned.

You may want to use a wrapper function (or write your own modified wrapper) that returns the geometries and not the nodes. You can take a look at the [workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html) for examples.

Comment: Actually I do want the all the rows for each query, with all the node information. I'd like to make intersections of these paths with other data.

Comment: technically, if you write a wrapper function that gives you back the entire route line, you can then intersect that line with other data very easily.