# How to create an OD road distance matrix in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, routing, network, cost-path

I'm looking for the steps required to produce an origin-destination (OD) cost matrix.

What I'm looking for is a matrix of **road** distances. The distance matrix tool only produces euclidian distances. The QGIS Roadgraph plugin produces the shortest road distance from **one** origin to N destinations. What I need is a file containing distances from **all** origins to the N closest destinations. I have a lot of origins so repeating the analyses with Roadgraph is not an option.

I'm looking for a step-by-step description, starting from scratch (ie, with my 3 shapefiles: origins, destinations, road network).

Comment: I guess pgRouting would be the best option for you.
Could you please have a look at these post and say if this is in general what you are looking for? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/creating-many-origin-destination-routes-with-pgrouting (Answer of Otto Coster)
If yes then there would be a additional loop neccessary do the calculations for all destinations

Comment: that's a useful start and seems very similar to what I am after. The only issues is I don't have access to PostGIS and was wondering if there are any QGIS plugins that would perform the same analysis

Comment: QGIS itself does not generate a network topology for calculating road distances out of the box. therefore you need something like pgRouting or perhaps GRASS-Modules as an alternative. you could have a look at https://jcastellssala.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/basic-network-analysis-with-grass/and grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.allpairs.html

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE - QGIS3:**

Since this seems to be an important topic, I would like to share my answer on a similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292519/distance-matrix-with-2-point-shapefiles-and-one-street-network/292537#292537).

If you are using the current version of **QGIS** (3), you can use the plugin **QNEAT3**. It offers **multiple processing algorithms** that produce origin-destination matrices (OD-Matrix) as line layer, table or csv file out of the box.  All algorithms rely on the `dijkstra()` method in the `qgis.analysis` module, therefore all costs are calculated on the basis of shortest paths and make use of C++ code for faster execution.

You can get more information about the plugin at the **[qgis plugin repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/)** and at the plugins **[documentation](https://root676.github.io)**.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS has all the algorithms necessary, but there is no GUI to create matrices yet. With some Python knowledge the [Network Analysis library documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS there is the Distance Matrix tool from the top bar: vector/analysis tools/distance matrix tool (I hope the translation is right because of my territorial version).