# Is there a QGIS equivalent to ArcGIS's Make OD Cost Matrix Layer (Network Analyst)?

Tags: qgis, network

I'm looking to create a OD cost distance matrix for a network data set I have created. Is there a way of doing this in QGIS which is akin to Make OD Cost Matrix Layer within ArcGIS's Network Analyst.

My question is similar to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73766/creating-an-od-cost-matrix-in-qgis) but there was no satisfactory answer given then. That question was asked nearly months ago and am wondering if there is a potential solution.

Comment: Welcome to  gis.stackexchange! Please note that threads should not be duplicated. Instead, attention can be drawn to the original post by updating it and/or adding bounties. Duplicating threads makes it more difficult to find relevant information in the future.

Comment: OK added a bounty to the old one, should I delete this?

Comment: There's no need to delete this one.