# Find nearest road distance between two points for over 1000 points

Tags: qgis, distance, routing

I'm extremely new to QGIS and am learning the material on my own.

I have two CSV files with latitudes and longitudes, one has school address information and the other has fast food restaurant address information.

I would like to find the distances between the two and the distances between the two points. (If that makes sense)I don't want to use the Hub Line process since I need road distances and PGRouting isn't working for me for some reason.

I'm not sure even after downloading all the information, it will not open up.

Comment: similar http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171896/how-to-calculate-shortest-path-from-points-in-one-layer-to-points-in-another-lay

Comment: You'll need to reproject your data into a map projection that preserves distance; lat/long points are in angular measures and aren't good for distance calculations (except by more complicated math).

Comment: Can you describe why PGRouting isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you haven't already, you need to transform your data from x/y coordinates into a readable vector shapefile. Do this by clicking "Add Delimited Text Layer" for each. Select file format as CSV, where X field is Longitude and Y field is Latitude, then click OK. Ensure your projection in the project properties is compatible (Project Properties - enable "on the fly" transformations).

To find the network distances between two points, try the Road Graph plugin.

http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_road_graph.html